# What's the Missing Authentication for S3 to Google Storage using gsutil?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

There are lots of posting about copying over from S3 to GS, but I'm stumped on this one - all the authentication seems to be correct, what am I missing?

```
$ gsutil -m cp -r s3://ws-logs gs://ws-logs
AccessDeniedException: 403 AccessDenied
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>659EC2ADB59407E2</RequestId><HostId>mTnCaiVt0elcnN7eljLvmiwqPwQui6Hr/VPSrR3pKT1TpjQaqRo3ZKeNloa9QU9DjzTcQE+Fc1g=</HostId></Error>
CommandException: 1 file/object could not be transferred.

$ gsutil -m cp -r test.txt gs://ws-logs
Copying file://test.txt [Content-Type=text/plain]...

$ aws s3 ls ws-logs
                           PRE dt=2012-12-01/

                           [ lots more entries ]
```

So, as you can see, I can create an entry in my gs bucket, and I can list my S3 directories. Is there something else I'm missing?

**UPDATE**

It works when I log directly into a VM on Gcloud:

```
$ gcloud compute --project "my-sample" ssh --zone "us-central1-f" "random-machine"

[ Login ]

$ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]: <ENTERED KEY>
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: <ENTERED KEY>
Default region name [None]: us-west-2
Default output format [None]: json
$ gsutil -m cp -R s3://ws-log gs://ws-log

[... Everything Copying Correctly ...]
```

Comment: The AccessDenied response is coming from S3 so I would assume that your IAM credentials, while valid for ListObjects, are not valid for GetObject (and/or some other action that gsutil invokes). Take a look at the IAM policy for the IAM credentials you are using.

Comment: Interesting data point - I just logged into my gcloud instance (`gcloud compute ssh ...`), entered the aws configuration via `aws configuration`, and it's working (from the command line). So it's just a Mac thing.

Comment: Use `gcloud auth list` on both machines and compare the accounts are `active`. It seems the one that you're using on your Mac machine does not have right permission to do the job. You can use `gcloud auth login` on your Mac to authenticate with an account that has write permission to the bucket.